# Refer to each genetic parameter in iterating of object entries where the values are uniform generics

Tags: typescript

### Target

Simplify

```js
type ControlsAccess = {
  age: ValidatableControlPayload<number, null>;
  prefecture: ValidatableControlPayload<string, null>;
};


const controlsAccess: ControlsAccess = {
  age: generateInitialValidatableControlPayload<number, null>({ initialValue: null })
  prefecture: generateInitialValidatableControlPayload<string, null>({ initialValue: null })
  // just two ones are enough for this example, but here could be the couple tens of entries
}
```

until:

```js
type ControlsAccess = {
  age: ValidatableControlPayload<number, null>;
  prefecture: ValidatableControlPayload<string, null>;
};

const controlsAccess: ControlsAccess = generateControlsAccessObject<ControlsAccess>({
  age: { initialValue: null },
  prefecture: { initialValue: null }
});
```

by implementationsof `generateControlsAccessObject` function.

Herewith, the `initialValue` of the `age` *must have* the type among generic parameters of `{ age: ValidatableControlPayload<number, null>; }`,
namely `number` or `null`. Same for the `prefecture`: in this case, `initialValue` must be one of `string` or `null`. The *must have* means that
when it no such as, the TypeScript error will be emitted.

I am not sure about it's possible, so the answer like "It's impossible because [argumentation]" is completely acceptable.
But if it's possible, maybe mentioned `generateInitialValidatableControlPayload` function could be used by `generateControlsAccessObject` for each entry.

```js
function generateInitialValidatableControlPayload<ValidValue, InvalidValue = ValidValue>(
  parametersObject: { initialValue: ValidValue | InvalidValue; }
): ValidatableControlPayload<ValidValue, InvalidValue> {
  return { 
    value: parametersObject.initialValue,
    // ....
 };
}

type ValidatableControlPayload<ValidValue, InvalidValue = ValidValue> =
  (
    {
      isInvalid: true;
      value: InvalidValue;
    } |
    {
      isInvalid: false;
      value: ValidValue;
    }
  ) &
  {
    validationPending: boolean;
    getComponentInstance: () => ValidatableControl;
  };
```

### My efforts

```js
function generateControlsAccessObject< 
  ValidValues, 
  InvalidValues = ValidValues
>(
  // Here will be the individual "ValidValue" and "InvalidValue" for each entry... but how to specify it?
  initialData: { [controlName: string]: { initialValue: ValidValues | InvalidValues; }; }
): GeneralizedControlsAccess {

  const accumulatingControlAccess: { [key: string]: ValidatableControlPayload<ValidValues, InvalidValues>; } = {};

  // This is working JavaScript but not valid TypeScript
  for (const [ key, data ] of Object.entries(initialData)) {
    // That's why I assign such title for this question.
    // We need to refer to the generic parameters of each `accumulatingControlAccess[key]`
    accumulatingControlAccess[key] = generateInitialValidatableControlPayload<ValidValues, InvalidValues>({
      initialValue: data.initialValue
    });
  }

  return accumulatingControlAccess as GeneralizedControlsAccess;
}

export type GeneralizedControlsAccess<ValidValues, InvalidValues = ValidValues> = {
  // Here will be the individual "ValidValue" and "InvalidValue" for each entry... but how to specify it?
  [key in string]: ValidatableControlPayload<ValidValues, InvalidValues>
};
```

[Initial code in TypeScript playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZlQJwIZVQYQSkzgBsBnAQQglXPIHkAjAK1WgB4BYAKEUQDi6LNlIwAXqgAmhMMTJUadcgBpEvfgDVRMKdtIg6ajYgCSYAG469ow+UQBeRPt367vAHwAKEwHpfiAASWKiIAO4wpKSITKFQABahMGBSMBa6IKKIAEQuNgao2YjYKTnmVmL5hkXAcJiIqNgQ8Q1ymACeAHTdMSBQiPFwYYhQcIjkAA7sMMDtiDBQAPwmyQswogAiuNgAXIgA3ogA2hBEJKQActgAtqh75MTJyAC6e4ersKJud87W3-YAHzMlj+tjoAG5EABfSFQ3gASj2QgwODEkhkZwU1Fo9AOvBMpzAD2KNBA1xApFwT1k8lI2OUb2OAGtUO17o8wC89nltkxSARMaQAArYdqkODYKQcPL-NTlUEFcgeWGOA4w-F8RD+RAAFXiMHsBvCdSZT0QAClsFYAMoQTAwCb9Jh9RBgOD9Cq6XXtKa2+2Oky1epeQnEo6IFntNRSbaIZ6IODARDMNjQTroR50LwfdakLZQbDw+F4zX8JoQMkUqmcmnnen0I6R+NONAo3CocxrL7WXn82tkEViiVSmVg1TAz1VOjefYmfj8HPdgp7GMFzqL0jfOfQ+HgkxwngmTCoKAgTBIcuVymwGuC+v2bD2ZEiNHSfsUe97ngH3ioAAeEx1P0UA+qEz6ohIb6CooOLkNKCp2HKIKVP8qqjoqHiqrOmrasEx7hJE0SxCMiTzCkaQZFkuQIYUxSlNk8ooWCNR1A0TQtBmHTdJ0vT9IMwyjOMUwQDMcwLMsmqNqyZHjByXK-JUvYCm0A6iuKkrwUxipIZO-weLw6qHkZoCQLACAoMIOB4J2nybj2BZ8sptKDupI40TpNFoTR3gmBM2A4LceCYIwrDsFAjIbt83KeUCjGuGCsIItFikOX2goucOmnxQUHlaYYmHYfwx6nueBzqJqACQFSGHsfkBSeWAhamUDrmAXZ2TlJgVQacVSHswCiOQqD7sU9g8qlTnnBlGnoYYuXZflkLaqYUAAOT2AwADSnQGRqvAgVMCm6Ep77TW5eWoPNU5eRdmEOCYPiliW87zj1yG6HsxCGF+L38NVPy9d8P3zlCiAAtuhW-W9k79YNqDAy9-3JQt8Pbge-Dwn4ABUiD8mt9hwNcCzzP0WO+Lw2r8NhlPzpOVIIEK6CpJyexMHAZCNGAX40-waBQIQ1yARgcjmA8JS0HsXjFg4mHjdgjnvpCFMBPwhm-gBQFkUFA20Edq7y2lKnRJD+rIPEYhm1AvXmBMfSS9LmEWHAujA3zABK7NQAAovytxyAAYnUfpkGInJCiQ6TM8g9uOJhPuoH7UDA7UFbkIsMcy4gTsu0edAntaBZ4DqcA2bmGeO87UhfgeQA)

Comment: Just a note, in your example, `GeneralizedControlsAccess` is given as the explicit return type for `generateControlsAccessObject` (line 8 of your playground), but it looks like the return type you actually want is something like `{ [key: string]: ValidatableControlPayload}` because `generateInitialValidatableControlPayload<ValidValues, InvalidValues>` returns a `ValidatableControlPayload` (line 14 of your playground)

Comment: In terms of your actual question, I'm having a little trouble following what you are asking.  Are you trying to figure out how to pass in an object with a bunch of initial values for each key, but also specify the full range of permitted values for each key?  It might be helpful if you could frame the question in terms of the ultimate function you want to end up with, since I suspect folks may be getting confused by all the implementation details here.

Comment: I'm having trouble following what is going on; it's helpful if the code posted is a [mre] without more details than necessary to demonstrate the issue.  Also, having generic type parameters with long type names like `ValidValue` is confusing; generic type parameters are given short one or two uppercase character names so that it's easy at a glance to tell which types are unspecified generics and which are specific types.

Comment: It *looks* like you are trying to have contextual typing infer one of the generic types from the expected return value, but I don't know why that's any simpler than, say, [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQKrVm), where you just let the compiler infer the type of `controlsAccess` instead of annotating it.  I don't see why `isInvalid: false` is acceptable as an initializer for `null` values you're passing in when `null` is the invalid value type.  Why not initialize them as invalid?  When you say "uniform generics" what do you mean? Are they all going to have `null` as an error?

Comment: My sincere hope is that you will edit this question to provide a [mre] that someone can just drop into an IDE and immediately see what the issue is without distractions.  If you think I'm focusing on some aspect of your question that isn't important, you should ideally remove that aspect from the question.  Good luck!

Comment: @sam256 "Just a note, in your example ..." - You are right. I'll fix it.

Comment: @sam256 " I'm having a little trouble following what you are asking." - I am sorry about the complicated question. To clarify the target, I modified the "Simplify ... until ..." part.

Comment: @sam256 "Are you trying to figure out how to pass in an object with a bunch of initial values for each key, but also specify the full range of permitted values for each key?" - Yes. "It might be helpful if you could frame the question in terms of the ultimate function you want to end up with, since I suspect folks may be getting confused by all the implementation details here." - Currently I have no IDEA for the better title. May I ask you to give me some more specific hint?

Comment: @jcalz, thank you for the comment. I am sorry but I have no idea how to simplify my example in TypeScript playground. Please give me some hint what I can safely remove from the example. "it's easy at a glance" - It is subjectively. Personally I has been confused by the unclear names like `T` and `U`.

Comment: @jcalz, "I don't see why isInvalid: false is acceptable as an initializer for null values you're passing in when null is the invalid value type." - I don't like it this too, but here is the unobvious reason - the Vue's `v-model`. It needs the non-undefined initial value, but then the component will override it once will be created.  I did not explain this moment because it does not require for the minimal example (we need to focus on valid `generateControlsAccessObject` implementation).

Comment: @jcalz "Why not initialize them as invalid?" - It's completely O'K. The reasons are again in Vue details. "When you say "uniform generics" what do you mean?" - I mean that value has same basic parameterized type. "Are they all going to have null as an error?" - in the real example - no. The `ValidValue` and `InvalidValue` combination could be arbitrary, the initial value should be one of `ValidValue` or `InvalidValue`.